# Can you add higher capacity internal drives than the listed on the official spec sheets?

Tags: ssd, mini-pc, upgrade

I have an HP EliteDesk 800 G5 and I wanted to add a couple of internal SSDs drives (4TB each), but the official specs list a maximum of 512GB for SATA3 connections.

I'm wondering if it would recognize the 4TB drives at all, I'm not sure if they are listing the maximum allowed or the types of combinations you can find the PCs with.

Can someone help me understand if these types of upgrades can work at all?

The official specs can be found here:
https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06403210

Comment: Hi, welcome to Hardware Recs! Unfortunately we don't answer questions about existing hardware compatibility here; we only focus on providing recommendations for new hardware. You may get more help on Superuser. That said, I'm 99% sure it would support 4TB drives; none of the hardware in that compute (SATA included) should limit drive size to 512 GB. The only limit you should really be aware of is that if you're using Windows, the legacy MBR partition type only works up to 2 TB; you'll want to use the GUID partition type instead.

Comment: @JMY1000 Sorry, first time here, didn't know about that. Thanks for answering the question anyway, I think I'm going to try the 4TB drives in that case.

Comment: All good! Welcome to SE!